# How to get valid firebase token in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification but when code gets executed it shows invalidresgistration error. Below is the code

LoginActivity

```
 String getToken = FirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefreshs();
String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
String URL = DataHolder.TokenUrl(getUsername,getToken);
```

`OnTokenRefresh` code

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    public static String onTokenRefreshs(){
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        return  token;
    }
}
```

pushnotification code

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

          $message = array("message" => "hell man");

     $xyz=array("firebasetokengoeshere I haven't included for now");
     $fields = array(
     'to' => json_encode($xyz),
     'data' => $message
     );

     $headers = array(
     'Authorization:key = Appkey goes here',
     'Content-type: application/json'
     );

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     if($result === FALSE){

     }
     curl_close($ch);

     return $result;



     $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
     echo $message;
```

> {"multicast_id":6744250798651355841,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

I am getting above result. How to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get token is:

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Your implementation of `FirebaseInstanceIdService` should contain the `onTokenRefresh()` method which is called automatically whenever a new token is created. You don't need to call it explicitly. You don't need to create it as your own method, as it is overridden. Moreover it should not be `static`. It should be something like this:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        // Store the token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the snippet below:

```
public class FirebaseCloudInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "Firebase";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + fcmToken);

    AppPref.saveFCMToken(this, fcmToken);
}
```

}

Usually, I will store the Firebase token in my sharedPref. And for more convenient, you can try my small util class which act as SharePref util for more handy. Find it here [android-shared-preference-util](https://github.com/cuongmanhvo162/android-shared-preference-util)